# Change Genesis <title> Tag from Page Template

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, title, genesis-theme-framework

I have made a page template for a Genesis theme in which I want to change the `<title>` tag but I can't find any API reference or example to do this.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Here's a complete list of all the filters http://my.studiopress.com/docs/filter-reference/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'my_custom_title');
function my_custom_title($title) {
    return 'My Custom Title';
}
```

Check genesis/lib/structure/header.php to see how Genesis does it.

Comment: … this would change the title for **all** pages on the site.

Comment: Place that code in the template page file (as opposed to `functions.php`). It would only run when WordPress uses that template file.

Comment: That changes the title (which you can do manually) but how does that change the title tag?

Comment: Increase priority in add filter like this:

`add_filter('wp_title', 'my_custom_title',15);
function my_custom_title($title) {
    return 'Gallery Image';
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any Genisis-specific way of doing this, but you can change the page title though the `wp_title` filter.

```
function foo_template_title( $title ) {
    return 'Foo Template';
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'foo_template_title' );
```

The next step is to check if the current page uses the Foo Template page template. Remember to replace `foo_template.php` with the filename of your page template:

```
function foo_template_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'foo_template.php' )
        return 'Foo Template';
    else
        return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'foo_template_title' );
```

See the WordPress Codex for more information on the [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) function and the [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) filter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_entry_header_markup_close', 15 );
```

Reference : http://my.studiopress.com/snippets/entry-header/